# how to manage two group fragments separately in one Activity?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

In my FragmentActivity, I have a FrameLayout and a SlidingDrawer, in the FrameLayout I manage a lot of fragments, and in the SlidingDrawer, its content I manage another fragments. But one activity seems to has only one backstack, how can I manage those two group fragments separately, means two backstacks?

eg: 
when slidingDrawer is closed:
***Fragment A*** to ***Fragment B*** to ***Fragment C***
when slidingDrawer is opende:
***Fragment Z*** to ***Fragment Y*** to ***Fragment X***
when slidingDrawer is closed, click back key, ***Fragment C*** to ***Fragment B***, 
then open, see Fragment X, click back key, ***Fragment X*** to ***Fragment Y***,
then close again, see Fragment B,click back key, ***Fragment B*** to ***Fragment A***,
then open again, see Fragment Y, click back key, ***Fragment Y*** to ***Fragment X***